# Is it possible to change a variables value from an array

Tags: java, arrays, gwt, variables, immutability

This is a little confusing question for me to express, but I'll do my best.

So:

```
ArrayList<Object> fieldList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

I then dump a lot of different variables to this array:

```
fieldList.add(objectsURL);   //string 

 fieldList.add(X);  //int 

 fieldList.add(Y); //int 

 ...
```

If I change the variable, the values in the array change 
 too-confirming the array stores a reference to the memory, rather 
 then value itself.

However, if I then retrieve data from the array then set that...

```
Object object = ((String)this.fieldList.get(0));
```

Then set object

```
object = "meeep!"
```

objectsURL is not set to "meep!" but rather it retains its original 
 value.

I assume this is because the "object" is not referencing the original 
 variable anymore, that instead its pointing to a new immutable string 
 in the memory.

All expected Java behavior I think....but then, how would I go about 
 setting the actual original variable? is this possible in java?.

So, in other words. Given only access to "fieldList" is it possible to change the value of 
"objectsURL"?

So, if:

```
String objectsURL = "www.google.com"
fieldList.add(objectsURL);
```

Is there a way to set objectsURL to "www.stackoverflow.com" using only a reference from fieldList? 
I dont want to change the fact that fieldList contains "objectsURL", I want to change what string the variable "objectsURL" actualy contains.

---

If not, is there an alternative method to achieve the same thing?

I hope my question explains the problem well enough.

My use-case is trying to make a serialization/ 
 deserialization system for a bunch of my objects. I was hoping to put 
 all the fields into a arraylist I could retrieve for both reading and 
 writing....thus avoiding having to hard-code long lists of 
 field[0]=blah and blah=field[0] and then going though constant pains 
 of needing to renumber them each time I add a new field before 
 another.

(I cant use Javas inbuilt serialization, as I am using GWT and this is client side only.)

Thanks,

Comment: What are the declarations for X and Y? Can you post a short, yet complete, program which reproduces the behavior you are asking about?

Comment: @Code-Guru The declarations of X and Y are irrelevant here, what darkflame is asking about is pretty clear.

Comment: @darkflame According to Java naming conventions, variables start with lowercase letter. I suggest the name `objectsURL` instead of `ObjectsURL`. `ObjectsURL` sounds like it's a class.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg ah, yes, of course, sorry about that. Edited for clarity.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg IMO, the question can be made much clearer with a complete example.

Comment: @Code-Guru After his edit of the question, I'm starting to agree with you... But the problem for the OP seems to be the code exactly ^^ But yes, a code example and an "expected result" would be helpful.

Comment: @darkflame Strings are immutable, so it is impossible to change the contents of a String object. Also, you cannot use the list to change what object the reference variable `objectsURL` points to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I assume this is because the "object" is not referencing the original variable anymore, that instead its pointing to a new immutable string in the memory.

Correct, each time you use the assignment operator `=` on an object **you change the object it refers to, not the object itself**.

To change the values in the List, you use the [.set method of an ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

`this.fieldList.set(0, newValue);`

**Since your variable is a String, there is no way you can change the String-variable through the list**

Your alternatives:

- using a char-array

  ```
  List myList = new ArrayList();
  char[] charArray = "My String".toCharArray();
  myList.add(charArray);
  charArray[0] = 'A';
  String theString = new String(myList.get(0)); // "Ay String"
  ```

If you use a char-array, make sure that the length of the array is enough to contain the number of characters you want to have in the future, because to change the length of the array you will need to create a new array (array lists can be expanded dynamically, arrays can not)

- Embed the String inside your own class (I have ignored getters and setters here)

  ```
  class MyString {
      public String value;
      public MyString(String value) {
          this.value = value;
      }
  }
  MyString myStr = new MyString("some value");
  list.add(myStr);
  ((MyString) list.get(0)).value = "a new value";
  System.out.println(myStr.value); // will print "a new value"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that first point.
Does that not just set the fieldList to contain that new value, rather then setting the variable already in the field list to the new value?
My goal is to set the original variable to a new value.


`fieldList.add(ObjectsURL);
this.fieldList.set(0, newValue);`

I dont think the value of "ObjectsURL" would change would it? which is what I am trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: You can of course use `this.fieldList.set(0, objectsURL);` after you have changed the value of `objectsURL`. The `.set` method of a list will overwrite the value at the existing index.

Comment: I have edited the above with a example to try to express this better.
I am trying to work out if I can change "objectsURL" with only access to the array.

Comment: `So, in other words. Given only access to "fieldList" is it possible to change the value of "objectsURL"?` As long as objectsURL is a String, no. As you said yourself, String is immutable. To change the value of a String you will have to use the `=` operator. You might want to change objectsURL to `char[]` (char array) or an object that **contains** a string, so that you could use `objectsURL.value = "A new value";` for example.

Comment: @darkflame I have updated my answer with the alternatives you have.

Comment: Thanks, Embeding the String inside its own class seems a good solution to my problem. I can do that to the other object types I need, and have a standard getter/setter implementation for them.
This should let loop over easily to set and retrieve the values for my custom serialize.....cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`String`s are immutable, so it is impossible to change the contents of a `String` object. Also, you cannot use the list to change what object the reference variable `objectsURL` points to. To achieve what you want, you will need to create a custom class that has a `String` member. You can then store instances of this class in a `List` and change the `String` references to via the references in the list. The changes will then be reflected in any other reference variables which refer to the objects in the list.